# TSLint No unused function on while() statement

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

In my Angular 6 component, I have the following function:

```
years: number[] = [];

private _getYears() {
    let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    let startYear = 2012;


    while (startYear <= currentYear) {
        this.years.push(startYear++);
    }
}
```

I'm receiving 'unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)' on my while statement. Why is this happening?

[image: Function]